# php mysql update two tables/columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my tables: **blocked_peoples** and **members**.
In table **blocked_peoples** column **ips** = **members** column **signup_ip**.

Let's say i wanna block person from accessing my site. I block user by his IP and it too update members table and column **banned** with **1**.

In short, if i update table blocked_peoples (column ips) and it's result found/same as members (column signup_ip) in members table update column banned with 1.

It's possible ? If yes, how sql will look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE blocked_peoples, members
   SET members.banned = 1 
 WHERE members.signup_ip = blocked_peoples.ip 
   AND blocked_peoples.ip = 'ip.address.goes.here';
```

That's the best I can come up with based on your question. I'm not sure though. It doesn't make sense to use two tables in the update since members table has both the ip and the "blocked" flag.

Answer (score 0):

STEPS:

- first make both table engine to INNODB
- then create a foreign key reference with constraint ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
- parent_table(blocked_people).ips will be referenced to child table(members).signup_ip

for more information read about foreign key reference .

Happy To HELP  :)

Comment: Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting rid of the `blocked_peoples` table completely if the relationship to `members` is 1-to-1. Otherwise, you should remove the `banned` column from `members` and rely specifically on the `blocked_peoples` to check for banned IPs.

Example Update:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `banned` = 1 WHERE `signup_Ip` = '123.123.123.123';
```

Example Select:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `banned` = 1
```